# Error trying to export contents of datagridview to excel

Tags: excel, csv, datagridview

I'm trying to export the contents of my dgv to excel, but I'm having a few errors.
My code is:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;"
Dim dbSource As String = "Data Source = C:\D&R\Data\DR.accdb"
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String
Dim query As String = "SELECT AcctNum,SDI,Medicare,State,Fed,TotWages FROM Earnings INNER JOIN Personel On Earnings.SS=Personel.SS"
Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn)

Private Sub connect()
    conn.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    conn.Open()
    MsgBox(conn.State.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub dgPopulate()
    connect()
    da.SelectCommand = command
    da.Fill(ds)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    Me.dgEmployees.DataSource = dt
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub export()
    Dim dgCount As Integer
    dgCount = dgEmployees.Rows.Count
    Dim output As New List(Of String)
    For Each intAccNum As DataGridViewRow In dgEmployees.Rows

        Dim empNumber As String = intAccNum.Cells(0).ToString
        For i = 1 To 5
            output.Add(empNumber + "," + CStr(intAccNum.Cells(i).Value + vbCrLf))
        Next
    Next
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\users\fantus\documents\test.txt", output.ToArray)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dgPopulate()
End Sub

Private Sub ExportToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExportToolStripMenuItem.Click
    export()
End Sub

End Class
```

I'm getting the error:

```
"Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."
```

on:

```
output.Add(empNumber + "," + CStr(intAccNum.Cells(i).Value + vbCrLf))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `vbCrLf` to `.value`. Convert just `.value` to a string and add the carriage return after.